# Angular-meteor conflict with pbastowski:angular-babel and webpack:webpack

Tags: angularjs, meteor, webpack, angular-meteor

I'm trying to use webpack with my angular-meteor application. Unfortunately the meteor build fails with the following error:

```
While determining active plugins:
    error: conflict: two packages included in the app (pbastowski:angular-babel and webpack:webpack) are both trying to handle *.js
```

The angular-meteor package has a dependency on pbastowski:angular-babel for ES2015 support, while webpack uses the babel-loader. Any idea how I can avoid this conflict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Meteor message that will appear when two Meteor packages try to add a Meteor compiler plugin for the same file extension, in this case ".js".

#### Option 1

Remove `webpack:webpack` from your project. Do you really need webpack in your Meteor project? Meteor bundles everything for you, so, there is no need to use webpack, as such. If you want to use ES6 modules then consider using `pbastowski:systemjs`.

```
    meteor remove webpack:webpack
```

I don't know your reasons for using webpack, but I thought I'd mention this option.

#### Option 2

You can configure `pbastowski:angular-babel` to not compile ".js" files by adding the line below to `babel.json` in your Meteor project's root folder. However, if you do this, Babel will only compile ".es6.js" files and not ".js" files.

***babel.json***

```
{
    "extensions": ["es6.js"]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the babel.json hint, Paul. I'm trying to use webpack to provide code splitting and dynamic module loading. Webpack has a babel loader (and an ngannotate loader) so it can handle compiling my .js files. BTW, I just recently saw the meteor 1.3 beta which looks like it will provide the capabilities I'm looking for, so I may just wait for that.

Answer (score 1):

Some people here are trying to say that Webpack is useless but they really don't know much about it.

- It can helps you bundle a lot better your assets.
- You can bundle better your CSS and even have local CSS (css that is not applied globally but only in a section of your page)
- You can do code splitting and not serve your entire app on the first page load
- You can have hot-reloading with no page refresh (at least with React ;))

You can use angular and Webpack together without any problem. Here is what you need to do:

`meteor remove angular
meteor add angular-meteor-data
meteor add angular-templates`

The only missing piece then is ng-annotate and luckily, there is a few ways. You can use the `ng-annotate-loader` or `ng-annotate-webpack-plugin` in your Webpack config file.